# COM dll registration is not a valid win32 application

Tags: c#, c++, dll, com, midl

I'm trying to use COM interop, specifically with .net core and C++. I have a .net core library which I'm trying to expose to a C++ codebase.

- I've created my own IDL file that declared the interface I wanted
- Via `midl.exe` a corresponding `.tlb` file was created
- I've registered the `comhost.dll` with `regsvr32` (64 bit client) and as a result, I can see the registration (with the error invalid Win32 application):

[image]

However, when I try to create an instance of said COM object, it tells me that it's not a valid win32 application.

**Settings used to publish the dll**
[image]

I've also tried creating an instance with `New-Object`:

```
$object = New-Object -ComObject GrpcLibrary.KioskProcessor
```

Which gave me the error saying that it couldn't create an instance of the COM object, error code: 80131513 method doesn't exist (HRESULT 0x80131513)

**Environment** (running Windows 11 ARM64 VM on Mac M3)

[image]

At the moment I'm unsure what I'm doing wrong, and why I cannot create an instance of the COM object. Also tried the solution mentioned [here](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365/microsoft-office-arm64-and-native-com-add-ins/m-p/3689596) by adding `Arm64X` in a `PropertyGroup` in the `csproj` file.

**Update**

The `cs` class where I've provided `ComVisble(true)` as an annotation:

```cs
[ComVisible(true)]
[Guid("9526a66b-200b-4157-aedc-56f084962031")]
[ProgId("GrpcLibrary.KioskProcessor")]
public class KioskProcessor : IKioskProcessor
{
    private readonly GrpcChannel channel;

    public KioskProcessor(string ipAddress = "http://localhost:50051")
    {
        channel = GrpcChannel.ForAddress(ipAddress);
        ....
    }

    ...
```

Comment: Exporting C# (or .Net) code involves adding attributes to your .Net code, you should not have to write a COM idl file at all. WIth the right attributes the .Net dll then becomes a registerable COM dll which you can use from C++ (using ATL's CreateComInstance). However COM adds a whole layer of complexity (threading models/registration etc.) so my advice would be to not use COM at all and write a C++/clr wrapper (managed C++). For a quick intro see : https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19354/Quick-C-CLI-Learn-C-CLI-in-less-than-10-minutes

Comment: Unlike in .NET, there's no support in .NET Core for generating a TLB, meaning you'd have to write an IDL file and compile with the C++ SDK midl to generate a TLB. I'll also take a look at the C++/CLI wrapper and how this integrates with .NET core, thanks for that suggestion. Nevertheless I'll still look for a solution for my current issue.

Comment: Is the c++ project managed or not managed?  If you are building a managed c++ project you do not call it as a COM.  You can call methods directly like any other c# child project.

Comment: Have you tried to publish using target runtime win-x86? using .net 6, I've succesfully exposed a c# class (`<ComVisible(True)>`) to com with this x86 setting.

Comment: @thewallrus Interesting, that does seem to work, does give me an error "no parameterless constructor defined", which I suppose could be correct given my current .idl. 64-bit compilers are backward compatible with x86, but it's "strange" why it wouldn't work with win-arm64.

Comment: @jdweng The c++ project is not managed.

Comment: First error seems a 32bit vs 64bit and/or Arm vs Intel issue. The other one is more unusual. Do you have a reproducing project?

Comment: @SimonMourier I agree first with your statement in regards to the 32bit vs 64bit and/or Arm vs Intel issue. The second issue "no parameterless constructor defined", is most likely due to the constructor I currently have (take a look at my initial post under the "updated" block). I suppose that's an extra element to why introducing COM is complex, having _only_ parameterless constructors.

Comment: Your object must have a parameterless public constructor. Optional arguments are just syntactic .NET sugar, the current ctor is not really parameterless.